# How to make "Glowing Effect" for shape in Android Studio?

Tags: android, xml, android-studio, kotlin, android-layout

I want to make square with glowing effect like this
[image]

But, i tried my best and i got this ( i know how to change style of text, just stuck with glowwing effect)
[image]

I'm using minAPI 31 & Kotlin

`item_square.xml`

```
    <View
        android:id="@+id/history_item_background"
        ...
        android:background="@drawable/history_item_background" />

    <View
        android:id="@+id/history_item_shadow"
        ....
        android:background="@drawable/history_item_shadow"
```

`history_item_background`

```
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <solid android:color="#7F08A2"  />
    <corners android:radius="50dp" />
</shape>
```

`history_item_shadow`

```
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
       android:windowBackgroundBlurRadius="30dp"
        android:windowBlurBehindEnabled="true"
        android:windowBlurBehindRadius="10dp">
    <solid android:color="#AC10D1" />
</shape>
```

How can I make it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is this xml shape you are expecting (you can experiment with various position of left, right, top and bottom of second item on the list, to obtain thicker or thinner frame):
[image]

If so, xml code for this element is:

```
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >

<item>
    <shape android:shape="rectangle">
        <solid android:color="#7F08A2" />
    </shape>
</item>
<item
    android:left="40dp"
    android:right="40dp"
    android:top="40dp"
    android:bottom="40dp"
    >
    <shape
        android:shape="rectangle"
        android:windowBackgroundBlurRadius="30dp"
        android:windowBlurBehindEnabled="true"
        android:windowBlurBehindRadius="10dp"            >
        <solid android:color="#AC10D1" />
        <corners android:radius="50dp" />
    </shape>
</item>
</layer-list>
```